# Parsing file via 'iter' excludes a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is driving me crazy, help is appreciated. Here's what I'm trying to do:

With a JSON file as input, find two consecutive lines that look like:

```
{
     "description"
```

Then, if that condition is found, insert additional JSON above this point. Following code *almost* works **except** that for some reason that I can't figure out, one line is getting skipped.

Code:

```
with open('file.in',encoding="utf8") as in_file:
    with open('file.out','w',encoding="utf8") as out_file:

        tag_to_check_line1 = '{'
        tag_to_check_line2 = '"description"'
        tag_to_check_not_line2 = ',"description"'
        irofile = iter(in_file)
        for line in irofile:
            if tag_to_check_line1 in line:
                out_file.write(line)
                line = next(irofile)
                if tag_to_check_line2 in line and tag_to_check_not_line2 not in line:
                    out_file.write('\n')
                    out_file.write('"fields": {\n')
                    out_file.write('"project":\n')
                    out_file.write('{\n')
                    out_file.write('"key": "GID"\n')
                    out_file.write('},\n')
                    out_file.write(line)
            else:
                out_file.write(line)
```

Input data looks like:

```json
 {
        "description": "<p>The description is here.</p>",
        "customfield_16818": "REQ-7591",
        "customfield_16819": "GID-1214020",
        "customfield_16815":{"self":"https://jira.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/20685","value":"No","id":"20685"},
        "summary": "MySQL Redundancy",
        "customfield_16816": "0",
        "customfield_16817": "0",
        "tag": "tagtext"
    }
```

The resulting output looks right, except that the `"summary"` tag is missing:

```
 {

"fields": {
"project":
{
   "key": "GID"
},
        "description": "<p>The description is here.</p>",
        "customfield_16818": "REQ-7591",
        "customfield_16819": "GID-1214020",
        "customfield_16815":{"self":"https://jira.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/20685","value":"No","id":"20685"},
        "customfield_16816": "0",
        "customfield_16817": "0",
        "tag": "tagtext"
    }
```

So the question is: **Why** is the `"summary"` tag missing?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Why are you doing all this weird, kludgy string manipulation instead of parsing and serializing the JSON with `json.loads` and `json.dumps`?

Comment: Also, `"customfield_16815":{"self":..` has a `{` in it.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I agree, it's fairly inelegant. Problem is that the original input file has *some* JSON in it, some just debug text, so I have to do a bunch of cleanup before I even get a good JSON-only file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `else:` clause. Can be fixed as indicated below:

```
with open('file.in',encoding="utf8") as in_file:
    with open('file.out', 'w', encoding="utf8") as out_file:
        tag_to_check_line1 = '{'
        tag_to_check_line2 = '"description"'
        tag_to_check_not_line2 = ',"description"'
        irofile = iter(in_file)
        for line in irofile:
            if tag_to_check_line1 in line:
                out_file.write(line)
                line = next(irofile)
                if tag_to_check_line2 in line and tag_to_check_not_line2 not in line:
                    out_file.write('\n')
                    out_file.write('"fields": {\n')
                    out_file.write('"project":\n')
                    out_file.write('{\n')
                    out_file.write('"key": "GID"\n')
                    out_file.write('},\n')
                    out_file.write(line)
                else:                           # ADD THESE
                    out_file.write(line)        # TWO LINES
            else:
                out_file.write(line)
```